# Cordova Ionic App doesn't respond after loading on ios

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing a hybrid app for android and iOS but i think i'm getting a connection problem or my app freezes. When I test on my iPhone, sometimes it works perfectly but sometimes after the splash screen has finished loading, the login screen doesn't allow me to click on the form boxes to enter text.

With android I can enter text but when I click the login button nothing happens - its usually supposed to show a loading popup and then log me in.

Does anyone know how I can fix these problems?

Cordova Version: 6.2.0
Ionic Version: 1.7.16
Node js: 2.15.8

Comment: Try to run on browser with 'ionic serve' and console the response and check for any error.

Comment: i have, it works perfectly fine with ionic serve just not when i test it on a real device

Comment: @AN11 any update on flicking issue because i am also getting the same flickering issue on running the app on a ios device while scrolling the content